# Starling: How to speed up the queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asynchronous, workling, starling-server

I've launched a website today which makes heavy use of Starling and Workling to handle the background task queue.

Traffic has been heavy and although my server CPU/memory has not been under too much strain, the job queue is seriously backing up.

I am inexperienced with both Starling and Workling and urgently need to understand how I can speed up the queue.

This is probably quite a simple configuration issue but all suggestions and thoughts would be very appreciated.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to another server you can split the tasks up between the servers. You've probably seen it but Railscasts has a pretty good [introduction to Starling and Workling](http://railscasts.com/episodes/128-starling-and-workling).

There is also a book you can view on Google books with more advanced information:

[Practical Rails Plugins](http://books.google.com/books?id=c1L4IzmUzicC&pg=PA284&lpg=PA284&dq=how+to+distribute+tasks,+starling+and+workling,+rails&source=bl&ots=0LgV4pDjs9&sig=4c6qf1GN59T-BsxGMpYDWU4XKrk&hl=en&ei=d5rJSfX6Gor2sAPzoLH4Bw&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=3&ct=result#PPA283,M1)

Answer (score 1):

I worked out how to do this in the end, it's very simple. Just start up more workling processes from the command line - there can be as many running as there is memory for. They will all pick up jobs from one or more instances of Starling, as specified in workling.yml. Note that `:multiple` must be `=> true` in `script/workling_client` for this to work.

Comment: May sound stupid, but is nice to check if you worklings are using the Workling::Remote::Invokers::ThreadedPoller.

This way, each one of your workers will have his own thread inside the workling process.